# How should I understand "archaeocyte" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, sentence

Consider the following sentence:

> The fossil consists of a complete skull of an archaeocyte, an extinct group of ancestors of modern cetaceans.

<s>Does it mean "the fossil consists of a complete skull; the fossil consists of an archaeocyte; and the fossil consists of an extinct group of ancestors of modern cetaceans"?</s>

**Added:**
What does the sentence mean and how should I understand "archaeocyte" here?

In the Merriam-Webster dictionary, "archaeo-" means "ancient" and "-cyte" means "cell". It seems that it doesn't make sense if "archaeocyte" means "an ancient cell" in this sentence.

The sentence is from an article in ETS's *The Official Guide to the TOEFL Test*(third edition).

Comment: Why downvote? Is the question too stupid? Any suggestion for making it better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase after the comma is simply explanatory, in that it defines *an archaeocyte*.

The fossil itself consists of just a complete skull, specified in more detail by the words following.

Per *@Stan Rogers* comment below, the sentence as written is factually incorrect. "Archaeocytes" are primitive sea-sponges, or types of cell; the ancestors of modern cetaceans are "Archaeocetes" (easy mistake to make!). But we're concerned with parsing the syntax here, not the objective truth of the statement.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I think my confusion is from the word "archaeocyte". Since "-cyte" means cells in the dictionary, I am totally confused with "a skull of an archaeocyte" and I have no idea how a cell can be "an extinct group of ancestors of modern cetaceans".

Comment: @Jack: Perhaps you could provide the source of your quote. It looks like complete tosh to me, given that *archaeocyte* seems to mean either a type of cell, or a primitive sea-sponge. I seriously doubt any such animal has ever given us a "fossilised skull".

Comment: ...for your edification, the actual ancestor in the quote probably should have been [indohyus](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2007/12/071220220241.htm), as discovered/announced a few years back.

Comment: +1. Fair enough. The key point is the understanding of "archaeocyte". This sentence is from an article in the TOEFL official guide.

Comment: Ah well. Just goes to show TOEFL are more focussed on grammatical structure than statement truth. I've seen stuff here before that gives me a very low opinion of these test papers.

Comment: +1. I really appreciate your comment that "... more focussed on grammatical structure than statement truth".

Comment: Just for further explanation, the word for one of the class of animals representing ancient (an transitional) cetaceans, is ***archaeocete*** (a member of *archaeocetidae*, or "ancient whales").

Comment: @Stan Rogers: Thanks for that! Makes a bit more sense now. And at least some hack connected with TOEFL can claim it was just a 1-letter glitch, not total rubbish.

Answer (score 2):

The quote says two things:

> 1. The fossil consists of a complete archaeocyte skull.
> 2. An archaeocyte is an extinct group of ancestors of modern cetaceans.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase after the comma is referring to *archaeocyte*, in the same way in the following sentence "the place" is referred to *East Hampton*.

> Her sister passes the summer at East Hampton, the place where they parents have bought their summer house.

As for the meaning of the sentence, I only found that *archaeocyte* is the name given to amoeboid cells found in sponges. If it is so, then an archaeocyte should not have a skull.

Comment: +1.  Thanks for your answer and explaining of "archaeocyte".